# Flutter iOS run on simulator fails: Undefined symbol: _OBJC_CLASS_$_EAAccessory

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I have upgraded my Flutter code to `Flutter 2.5` and since then there is an error each time I try to run the app on simulator. It runs fine on the real device, but on simulator I find this error:

[image]

I checked the libraries I use and all are added in the Build Phases.

Any help?

Answer (score 3):

On your terminal, go to **project's** folder and go to **ios** folder then you can delete the **podfile.lock**, **Pods** folder, **.symlinks** folder.

Then run `flutter clean`, `flutter pub get`, and run `pod install --repo-update`.

Then open the project on XCode and click **SHIFT + CMD + K** to clean the build folder.

After that try running again and let me know if works.

Comment: I tried it and it still doesn't work

Comment: Work for me, ty